# building plugin and it is displaying above plugins page

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

this is the issue:

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'bittech_login_settings');



function bittech_login_settings() {



add_menu_page('BitTech Login Settings', 
              'BitTech Login Settings', 
              'administrator', 
              'bittech_settings', 
              'bittech_login_settings');

$filename = "../wp-content/plugins/bittech_login/include/config.php";

$contents = file_get_contents($filename);

if (isset($_POST['field'])) {
   file_put_contents($filename, $_POST['field']);
}
?>

<form action="" method="POST">
    <textarea name="field" cols="300" rows="200"><?php 
    echo $contents; 
    ?></textarea><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>
<?php
}
?>
```

the code is working correctly but when it is put in it appears above the plugin panel. i was wondering what the fix for this was. that way i dont have this issue in the future. i would like to add that i am very new to making plugins hence why i am having the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `add_menu_page` wrong. The function `bittech_login_settings` should be only:

```
function bittech_login_settings() {
    add_menu_page(
        'BitTech Login Settings', 
        'BitTech Login Settings', 
        'add_users', 
        'bittech_settings', 
        'bittech_login_settings_callback'
    );
}

function bittech_login_settings_callback() {
    // content of the menu
}
```

And put the contents of the page in the callback function `bittech_login_settings_callback`. Also, these lines don't make much sense:

```
$filename = "../wp-content/plugins/bittech_login/include/config.php";
$contents = file_get_contents($filename);
if($_POST) file_put_contents($filename, $_POST['field']);
```

You should probably store that field in the database with [`update_option`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_option) and retrieve it with `get_option()`.

Answer (score 1):

The [Codex provides guidance for determining which `add_*_page()` call to use](http://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Menus#Determining_Location_for_New_Menus) for a given menu item.

You're using [`add_menu_page()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu_page), which adds a **top-level menu**. You could try using a more-appropriate sub-menu; perhaps one of the following three:

- [`add_options_page()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_options_page) - add a submenu to `Settings`
- [`add_management_page()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_management_page) - add a submenu to `Tools`
- [`add_plugins_page()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_plugins_page) - add a submenu to `Plugins`

Refer to the Codex entry linked above for additional options.

Comment: no thats not the issue i have it placed in the menu where i want it but the code also appears above everything in the admin panel.

Comment: Then can you please **edit your question** to clarify *exactly* what the problem is? **What specific code** is appearing, and where?